# How to restrict user from adding images to Enhanced Notes in Lightning for some custom objects

Tags: lightning, notes

Is it possible to restrict user from adding images in the Enhanced Notes for **specific** custom objects. The image button is highlighted as shown in the below image.

[image]

As we in Lightning have requirements not to upload the images in Notes rather user should be using Files to upload any document or images.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to suppress the image button from the ContentNote RichText Editor. What you could do is place a trigger to prevent insertion of a ContentNote that has `<img>` tags in the body of the ContentNote. ContentNote ERD: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm#!

Comment: Thank you Glen. But I am not sure how to add trigger to restrict the image based on the <img> tags. Can you please guide.

Comment: @GlenDeMarcos, in trigger I have tried for ContentNote, ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink object for TextPreview field, I am not getting any <img> tags. For content field it is showing as '/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentNote/someId/Content'.

Comment: It seems you are not alone: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005rKPQAY 
This might complicate the trigger as it doesn't allow callouts - you would likely have to call a future method with (callouts=true) to perform the action asynchronously but that would not be able to prevent insert. The documentation on ContentNote is definitively not clear. ContentNote is a ContentVersion masked (its ContentDocument of Type SNOTE). A trigger on ContentVersion could be an option but I'm seeing the same behavior on that object. Validation rules also don't have content fields :(

Comment: Thank you Glen, for your inputs.

Comment: If you find a path forward please document it here. The only way to control the upload is to have a custom component that controls the upload where you can analyze the content before it is inserted. This would need to be true as well with any Salesforce antivirus (there are some in the appexchange).